# Does the rearrangement of a series of positive numbers change the sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ is a sequence such that $a_{n}\geq 0$ for each n, then if we rearrange this series, will it change the final sum? the sum may be infinite, we have riemann rearrangement theorem that if the sum of this series is finite, then the rearrangement doesn't affect the total sum, but what if the sum is infinite?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: The riemann arrangement theorem states something different : If we have a conditional converging series (that means the sum with the absolute values diverges) , then for every real number $r$ , we can rearrange the summands such that the series converges to $r$. There are also rearrangements that are divergent,

Comment: If the series is however absolute convergent (or if it converges and has already positive entries , it is even sufficient that from some index on all entries are positive) , then rearranging the summands does not change the value of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ are $\ge 0$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \ \ ( = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n )= \sup_{I \subset \mathbb{N} \\ I \textrm{finite}} \sum_{n\in I} a_n $$

RHS shows that the sum of the series does not change under a rearrangement.